# How can i make specific output using a strip function?

Tags: python, strip

I am trying to remove some symbols from output, but it does not work. I've tried many ways to do this, also i searched many similar questions, but i still don't have an answer. Here is the code:

```py
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test;")
all = cur.fetchone()
str1 = str(all)
str2 = str1.strip("()")
str3 = str2.strip(",")
str4 = str3.strip("()")
str5 = str4.strip("''")
str6 = str5.strip("', '")
print(str6)
```

The output is:
`f', 'f`
Instead of:
`f f`
Sorry for bad code. Thanks for help

Comment: what do you try to do? please explain.

Comment: what does the `str1` contain? depending on that you might not need all these `strip()`s.

Comment: balderman, i am working with SQL, so the basic output is ('f', 'f'), and i want it to be just f, f.
Krishna Chaurasia, str1 transforms "all" variable with list type to string type

Comment: You might want to check `join` and `replace` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `.replace()` function

```py
string = "f', 'f"
string = string.replace("', '", " ")
print(string)
```

Outputs:

```
f f
```

Comment: Sure this is answering the question he posted, but it would not result in good code. Given what he is trying to achieve, the better way to approach it would be to iterate through the response and output each item rather than converting an iterable to a string and replacing characters.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are asking.  Strip pulls characters off of either side of the string if they exist.  You may be looking for the .replace() method instead.

Answer (score 0):

the `strip()`method only removes from left or right part of the string, not in the middle of the string. For that you would need to use `replace()`instead. **Note that the way you seem to approach this wouldn't result in good code and isn't the way you would handle a db response.**

**I would rather recommend the following:** The db call returns the result in a *tuple* datatype. In case you want to output the result from each individual item in the db call, i would rather recommend iterating through the result and converting each item to str rather than converting the entire result tuple to a string and replacing characters. The below would produce the output you are looking for and is a more correct way of going about it.

```py
db_result = ('f', 'f')
for item in db_result:
    print(str(item), end=" ")
print()
```